# Vim does not display other files in the same folder when opening a file

Tags: vim, vimrc

On a brand new debian installation, when no `~/.vimrc` is present, `vim` shows all files in the current directory when trying to open another file for editing in normal/command mode, as shown below:

[image: vim when pressing ":e"]

However, when a `~/.vimrc` is present, even an empty one, I suddenly cannot see other files in the same directory.

I am looking for the `vim` option that I have accidentally disabled, so that I can re-enable this behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are referring to is called the "wildcard menu".  This shows the filnames that match the pattern under the cursor when you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> after `:e`.  Since there is no pattern, all filenames are shown.

This "wildcard menu" is enabled by the [`wildmenu`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27wildmenu%27) option:

```
set wildmenu
```

Or,

```
set wmnu
```

The reason this option is on when you have no `.vimrc` file but off when that file exists is that the option is set in [`defaults.vim`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#defaults.vim) on your system.  The `defaults.vim` file is not used if Vim finds your `.vimrc` file.

The documentation for the `defaults.vim` file suggests that you start your `.vimrc` file with

```
unlet! skip_defaults_vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim
```

... to get the system defaults (which, in your case, would include setting the `wildmenu` option).

Comment: Thanks a lot, `wildmenu` was indeed the option I was looking for. For some reason, I couldn't find it.